# Issues upgrading Ruby 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 on Rails 3.2.22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Rails 3.2.22 and Ruby 2.0.0 on macOS 10.14.6. App functions properly and all tests pass - Rspec, 427 tests, 0 failures.

Gems are bundled into `/vendor/bundle`. I used `ruby-install` to install ruby versions and `chruby` to auto-switch according to a `.ruby-version` file. I also define ruby version in the `Gemfile` for Heroku.

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
...
```

```
# .ruby-version
ruby-2.0.0
```

When I move to Ruby 2.1.0 in the `Gemfile` and `.ruby-version` I can no longer `bundle install` or start the app:

```
$ bundle install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

```
$ foreman start
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem foreman (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /usr/local/bin/foreman:22:in `<main>'
```

I can't install bundler:

```
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

### WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR

If I go back to Ruby 2.0.0 in 'Gemfile' and `-ruby-version` the app runs but Rspec fails with lots of `warning: already initialized constant` for `activerecord`, `activesupport` and `paper_trail`, even though nothing has changed in the app, `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock`.

The only way to get it running again on Ruby 2.0.0 is to flush out the bundled gems with `bundle clean --force` then a fresh `bundle install`.

After the `openssl` error I removed Ruby 2.1.0 from `~/.rubies/` and reinstalled with option specifying the path to my `openssl` install (after finding it from `brew`):

```
$ brew --prefix openssl@1.0
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
$ ruby-install ruby 2.1.0 -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
```

Ruby 2.1.0 installed correctly and I try to install `bundler` I get:

```
$ gem install budler
Fetching: bundler-2.1.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
        bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

I install the specific version of `bundler` that created the `Gemfile.lock`:

```
$ gem install bundler -v "1.17.3"
Fetching: bundler-1.17.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.3
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.17.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 8 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But then `bundle install` fails saying that Ruby version is 2.3.7:

```
$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin18.0]
```

Looks like the reference to Ruby 2.3.7 is coming from here:

```
$ bundle env
## Environment

Bundler       1.17.3
  Platforms   ruby, universal-darwin-18
Ruby          2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  Full Path   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Library/Ruby/Site
RubyGems      2.5.2.3
  Gem Home    /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  Gem Path    /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  User Path   /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      0.3.9
```

I found this question: [Bundler using wrong Ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427016/bundler-using-wrong-ruby-version) with a comment to try `hash -r`:
"It could be that your shell has the old bundle command cached, try running hash -r. – matt"

This seemed to fix the hard-coded Ruby version in Bundle:

```
$ hash -r
$ bundle env
## Environment

Bundler       1.17.3
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-18
Ruby          2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin18.0]
  Full Path   /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/etc
RubyGems      2.2.0
  Gem Home    /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  Gem Path    /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  User Path   /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      0.3.9
```

Bundle now references Ruby 2.1.0 and I can successfully `bundle install`

But now I'm getting syntax errors when I run Rspec or start the app:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.10, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.4
/Users/dan/Documents/code/lessonmate/vendor/bundle/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/browser.rb:9:in `require_relative': /Users/dan/Documents/code/lessonmate/vendor/bundle/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/accept_language.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
        code&.downcase
```

```
$ bundle exec rails server
/Users/dan/Documents/code/lessonmate/vendor/bundle/gems/uniform_notifier-1.12.0/lib/uniform_notifier.rb:3:in `require': /Users/dan/Documents/code/lessonmate/vendor/bundle/gems/uniform_notifier-1.12.0/lib/uniform_notifier/base.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
      <<~CODE
        ^
```

---

With Ruby 2.0.0:

```
$RUBY_ROOT /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648
$RUBY_ENGINE ruby
$RUBY_VERSION 2.0.0
$GEM_ROOT /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
$GEM_HOME /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
$GEM_PATH /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
$PATH /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bin:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin:/Users/dan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dan/bin:/Users/dan/bin

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [x86_64-darwin18.7.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

With Ruby 2.1.0:

```
$RUBY_ROOT /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0
$RUBY_ENGINE ruby
$RUBY_VERSION 2.1.0
$GEM_ROOT /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
$GEM_HOME /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
$GEM_PATH /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
$PATH /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin:/Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/Users/dan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dan/bin:/Users/dan/bin

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin18.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dan/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
     - /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/dan/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/dan/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/dan/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/dan/bin
     - /Users/dan/bin
```

Comment: Have you tried to use RMV (http://rvm.io)? It completely automatise the dependencies installation when compiling the Ruby version you've asked. Another option is Docker, you take an image which is already done with all the Ruby stuff and import your project, but there's a leaning curve.

Comment: @ZedTuX In the past I have used RVM and rbenv but both have their downsides. I've settled on ruby-install and chruby as simpler, less intrusive methods of ruby management. I've been meaning to look into Docker for a while, for this very purpose, but I don't have time for it right now.